# Was Assir a son of Jeconiah or an attribute of him?

Tags: malchut-royalty, book-of-chronicles

In 1 Chronicles 3:17 in the most acclaimed versions it is stated that the sons of Jeconiah were Assir and Shealtiel.

Would it be a mistranslation to put Assir as if he were a person when it could be an attribute of Jeconiah as "captive" which is the meaning of Assir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @Harel13 notes there are differing opinions:

The [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.3.17?lang=bi&p2=Malbim_on_I_Chronicles.3.17.2&lang2=bi) spells out the differing viewpoints:

- There are those who say that "Assir" is descriptive of Yechonya since he was incarcerated in prison and there he gave birth to these sons.
- The opinion of the Sages is that Assir and Shealtiel were his sons; he had two sons, and Malchiram and Pedaya are the sons of Shealtiel.
- Alternatively, all of them were the sons of Yechonya.

The [Metzudos Dovid](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.3.17?lang=bi&p2=Metzudat_David_on_I_Chronicles.3.17.2&lang2=bi) says that Shealtiel was the son of Assir.

[Ralbag](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.3.17?lang=bi&p2=Ralbag_on_I_Chronicles.3.17.1&lang2=bi) says Assir was the son of Yechonya and Shealtiel was the son of Assir. Then, when it mentions Malchiram and Pedaya, they were the sons of Shealtiel.

Finally, [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.3.17?lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_I_Chronicles.3.17.1&lang2=bi) says that both Shealtiel and Assir were Yechonya's sons. And Assir was so called because he was born in prison.